# Flutter Matrix4 transformation overflow

Tags: flutter

Im trying to create row of cuboids using Translate widget in flutter, effect in screen below:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRgpK.png)

Im facing problem with restricting overflow of my cuboid, as you can see yellow face can be seen on black face of another cuboid (second from right). Is this possible to restrict visibility of cuboid faces just to parent Container? Any ideas will be appreciated.

```
Transform(
    transform: Matrix4.identity()
    ..scale(_scaleFactor)
    ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.0015)
    child: Row(
               children: [cuboid(), cuboid(), cuboid2, cuboid(), cuboid()])

)
```

Cuboid shape:

```
 Container(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.identity()
                      ..translate(0.0, yTranslate, 0.0)
                      ..rotateX(pi / 2),
                    child: Container(
                      width: width,
                      height: height,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      
                //BACK
            Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.identity()..translate(0.0, 0.0, zTranslate),
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  height: height,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  // ),
                )),
            //Left
            Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.identity()
                  ..translate(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                  ..rotateY(-pi / 2),
                child: Container(
                  width: widget.size,
                  height: widget.size,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                )),
            //Right
            Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.identity()
                  ..translate(xTranslate, 0.0, 0.0)
                  ..rotateY(-pi / 2),
                child: Container(
                  width: widget.size,
                  height: widget.size,
                  color: Colors.black,
                )),
            Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.identity()
                  ..translate(0.0, 0.0, zTranslate)
                  ..rotateX(-pi / 2),
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  height: width,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ))]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out.

In the cuboid in the parent Container I have added:
***clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge***.
This option is able to restrict visible area to container shape so I have archieved expectrd behavior.